# Carbon get month index from month name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'd like to get month index from month name using Carbon.

But I use Turkish month names.

I pass a query string to index like this `?ay=Temmuz&yıl=2017` so carbon should give 7 in this case.

The relevant part in my index function is like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $gonderiler = Gonderi::latest();

    if ($ay = request('ay'))
    {
        Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
        $gonderiler->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::parse($ay)->month);
    }

    if ($yil = request('yil'))
    {
        $gonderiler->whereYear('created_at', $yil);
    }

    / ... / 

}
```

When I click side bar and pass this query string it gives an error message like that:

> "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Temmuz) at
>   position 0 (T): The timezone could not be found in the database"

Comment: What is the server you are using?

Comment: I use vallet on 64 bit Ubuntu machine. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Laravel Framework 5.5.3

Answer (score 0):

**on Linux**

If you have trouble with translations, check locales installed in your system (local and production).

```
locale -a to list locales enabled.
sudo locale-gen tr_TR.UTF-8 to install a new locale.
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales to publish all locale enabled.
```

And reboot your system. see documentation: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

For more you can refer to: [Laravel Carbon localization not working (get localized name of month from number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073696/laravel-carbon-localization-not-working-get-localized-name-of-month-from-number)

As the error you are getting is about `Timezone` not found in database.

Comment: Locales are already installed. This error message is Laravel's exception error message. If I click side bar and pass this query string to index method. Like that http://gunluk.dev/?ay=Temmuz&yıl=2017

Comment: `Carbon` doesn't have parsing feature with month name.